# private method inside spring mvc controller is thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

As i understand spring mvc controllers are thread safe by default (like servlets). But  I just want to know any private helper methods inside the controllers are thread safe ?

I have two mapping in the controller class eg: /test and test/success. Every time user invokes this url I want to check the user status and activation time in the database using a service method ( two different calls ). So I have decided to create a one private helper method to check the status.
So could anyone know that my private method is thread safe ?

Comment: No, you are completely wrong on both of these points: _spring mvc controllers are thread safe by default (like servlets)_ What does visibility have to do with thread-safety?

Comment: mvc controller in singleton by default and when request comes new thread will be called just like servlets life cycles?

Comment: So how is that thread safe?

Comment: what I am saying is any local variable inside the mapping methods are thread safe. Not a instance variable.

Comment: Ok, that is completely different. That doesn't make a class thread safe in itself. And `private` has nothing to do with thread safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All request are handled by one instance of your controller (singleton because it's a spring managed bean). So you need to make sure to not store any state (in a field) related to one request.

So:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private Something something;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String foo() {
       something.someMethod();
       bar();
       return "view"
    }

    private void bar() {
        // something
    }
}
```

is OK, but:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class Foo {

    private User theUser; // problem is ALL request share this field

    @RequestMapping("/foo/{userId}")
    public String foo(@PathVariable final Integer userId) {
       if (theUser.getId().equals(userId)) {
           // something
       } else {
           theUser = ...
       }
       return "view"
    }
}
```

is not.

**NB: not tested (typed just here so it can even hurts your compiler)**

Comment: Yes. I should avoid private method. So I Think i need to call the service methods or write a same logic inside the two mapping methods?

Comment: this is what I exactly asked.... I have decided to do it like first example. Is that be thread safe if multiple user call the same url at the same time?

Comment: And we will be calling our service methods like your second example? Is that thread safe by default.

Comment: yes it is, but best practises recommends to **not** put any logic in controllers

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lost, my sample code are two opposal thing, you should edit your question and add your code.

Comment: I got the answer for the private method. What i am asking is we will create a service class object at the member level of the controller class with @Autowired when we invoke service method inside our controller mapping class , is that be thread safe?

Comment: Yes, you just "use" it, you don't assign to it. And as it's autowired by spring, it's done at bean instantiation/construction

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38570/discussion-between-karesh-arunakirinathan-and-rc)