# Spring MVC Controller Safe Thread for generating data

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have `Spring Controller` for saving data to database, and this method generating `receiptNo` (the receiptNo value is generated using some database field value) for example: `xxx/ddMMyy/compId`.

where `xxx` is `select max(substr("receiptNo")) from table`, and `compId` is from the `session`. After `receiptNo` is generated, then the value will be saved to another table.

my Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class foo{

private Object LOCK_OBJECT = new Object();

@RequestMapping(value = "/generateAndSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView generateAndSave(@ModelAttribute("tform") TempForm tform, HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Some Logic
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
           String max = doGetMax(tform);
           SomePojo domain = doGenerate(max, compId);
           doStore(domain);
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("key", "value");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

My Question is, Should i use `synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) { }` block for ensuring unique `receiptNo`?

My concern is on `xxx` value, if i not use `synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) { }` block, some user will get same `xxx` value.

Please Advise,

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168150/private-method-inside-spring-mvc-controller-is-thread-safe?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145761/are-spring-controllers-thread-safe) might help.

Comment: also elaborate if `doGetMax` and `doStore' are `private methods` of controller or methods of some service object.

Comment: yes, you should use `synchronized`. Spring does not care about synchronization, you should do it by yourself, otherwise different threads will be able to get same max value from database.